# images resizing using bootstrap and css3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with my images they are not responsive

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 visible-xs">
          <div class="overview-device-wrapper">
            <img src="img/landing/landing-app-left-overview.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
    /* Small decives (phones, 320px and up)*/
@media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) { 
    .overview-device-wrapper{

        width: 320px;
    }

}
```

the image does not appear properly in a mobile browser

[image on a pc screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm6Rm.jpg)
[image on a mobile browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mrze.jpg)

the image should appear on the left not at the bottom in a mobile browser

Comment: How does it looks like exactly? or can u show us some screenshot or link?

Comment: i uploaded the images

Comment: It's better show your demo link here so that you can get solution quick.

Comment: I'm new to bootstrap 3 i just want the image to appear in a mobile browser the same way it appears on a pc screen

Comment: @Thami sithole, You don't need to add separate media query for image responsiveness, It has own class for responsive images.

Comment: @Thamisithole then you should probably set its `height` not `width`, you are using `img-responsive` class anyways so you dont have to bother with the width.

Comment: Did you add to your headers `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`? check bootstrap docs basic templates ([link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template))

Comment: @VitorMateus yes i did

Comment: @Thamisithole, Your issue has solved?

Comment: @SayedRafeeq yes my problem was solved thanks for asking i'm sorry for this late reply thak you for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Responsive images**

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the

**Responsive Class**

> .img-responsive.

This applies **max-width: 100%;**, **height: auto;** and **display: block**; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

**Image Demo with Class:**

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```